# Google Maps API - maps.setCenter doesn't seem to be centering to users position

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been using the Google Maps API, and one thing is particularly bugging me.

I set the original Map on page load, and then once the user clicks a 'sign in' button and shares their location, an array of 'shops' with the distance calculated between the users position and the shops is displayed in an info window above the marker.

The problem I'm having - in Firefox - is that the array of shops loads, and the map centers in the middle of the shop positions instead of the map centering on the users location.

Some of the variables here are holding dummy content at the moment only.

When the last function (addDabblerArrayToMap) runs, it checks the 'centerPos' - the variable which holds the users location, and then does either one action or another: 
1. If centerPos = null, the markers are added to the map, and the default position is dropped on to the map, without any distance calculation occurring. 
2. If centerPos holds a lat & lng, then the distance between each shop and the user is calculated and appended to an infoWindow which is displayed above the relative shop marker, so a user can see how far away each shop is from their position.

- When this runs, map.setCenter(centerPos) does not center the map at the users position. It sets the map in the middle of the array of shops. I can enter the browser console and type in 'map.setCenter(centerPos)' - and it does then center the map to the users position.

Full Code below:

HTML:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<button onClick="runAllChainEvents();">Sign in</button>
```

CSS:

```
#map {
   height: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
var neighborhoods = [
    {lat: -36.862338, lng: 174.7425013},
    {lat: -36.867204, lng: 174.7692113},
    {lat: -36.848362, lng: 174.7426733},
    {lat: -36.845028, lng: 174.7748043},
    {lat: -36.862644, lng: 174.7340973},
    {lat: -36.862775, lng: 174.7836023}
];
var markers =[];
var map;
var dabblers = "../favicon-32x32.png";
var yourLocation = "../dabble-icon.png";
var myLocationIconArray = [];
var hasHappened = false;
var infoWindowContentString = '';
var dabblerInfoWindow = null;
var addInfowindow;
var distanceArray = [];
var defaultPos = {lat: -36.8527785, lng: 174.7617562};
var centerPos;

var dabblersArray = [
    {lat: -36.862338, lng: 174.7425013, type: 'sweet'},
    {lat: -36.867204, lng: 174.7692113, type: 'sweet'},
    {lat: -36.848362, lng: 174.7426733, type: 'sweet'},
    {lat: -36.845028, lng: 174.7748043, type: 'savoury'},
    {lat: -36.862644, lng: 174.7340973, type: 'savoury'},
    {lat: -36.862775, lng: 174.7836023, type: 'savoury'}
];

/* Initializes map with custom styles, centers location, 
   and defines Map UI */
function initMap() {
    var customMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType([
        {
          stylers: [
            {hue: '#8c8c8c'},
            {visibility: 'simplified'}
          ]
        },
        {
          elementType: 'labels',
          stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
        },
        {
          elementType: 'landscape',
          stylers: [{color: '#e6e6e6'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road',
          stylers: [{color: '#ffffff'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.highway.controlled_access',
          stylers: [{color: '#cccccc'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.arterial',
          stylers: [{color: '#cccccc'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'water',
          stylers: [
            {color: '#dce6e6'},
            {"lightness": -10},
            {"saturation": -30}
          ]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'poi',
          stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'transit.line',
          stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
        }
    ], { name: 'Custom Style'
    });   
    var customMapTypeId = 'custom_style';
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: { lat: -36.8527785, lng: 174.7617562}, // Auckland City coords
          zoom: 15,
          disableDefaultUI: true,
          zoomControl: false,
          mapTypeControl: false,
          scaleControl: false,
          fullscreenControl: false,
          streetViewControl: false,
          mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, customMapTypeId]
          }
    });
    map.mapTypes.set(customMapTypeId, customMapType);
    map.setMapTypeId(customMapTypeId);
    map.setOptions({draggable: false, zoomControl: false,
    zoomControlOptions: {
              position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER
          },
    scrollwheel: false, disableDoubleClickZoom: true});
    drop();
}

/* Takes positions in neighborhoodsArray and runs each through 
   the addMarkerWithTimeout function */
function drop() {
  var delay = 800;
    for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) {
      addMarkerWithTimeout(neighborhoods[i], i*200 + delay);
    }
}

/* Takes position (lat / long) and timeout parameters and converts 
   into Google Map Markers. Then adds to Google Map. */
function addMarkerWithTimeout(position, timeout) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        icon: dabblers,
        draggable: false,
        clickable: false
      }));
    }, timeout);
}

/*  Clears original markers from map and sets relative arrays to [] */
function deleteMarkers() {
    for (var x = 0; x < markers.length; x++) {
      markers[x].setMap(null);
    }
    markers = [];
    neighborhoods = [];
}

/* Adds your location & infoWindow to map after signIn */   
function addMarker(location, addInfowindow) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        icon: yourLocation,
        draggable: false,
        clickable: true
    });
    if (addInfowindow == null) {
        var myLocationInfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: "Your location"
        });
        myLocationInfowindow.open(map, marker);
        myLocationIconArray.push(marker);
    } else {
        var myLocationInfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: infoWindowContentString
        });
        myLocationInfowindow.open(map, marker);
        myLocationIconArray.push(marker);
    }
}

/* Checks if Users browser / device is capable of Geolocation. If it is, gets current position */
function getUserLocation(onComplete) {  
    map.setOptions({draggable: true, zoomControl: true, scrollwheel: true, disableDoubleClickZoom: false});

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            centerPos = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            map.setCenter(centerPos);
            addMarker(centerPos);
            onComplete();
        }, function() {
            handleLocationError(true, addInfowindow, map.getCenter());
        });
    } else {
        //Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        handleLocationError(false, addInfowindow, map.getCenter());
    }
}

/* Removes elements, and adds Dabblers to map */
function runAllChainEvents() {
    getUserLocation(addDabblerArrayToMap);
}

/* Handles error if Users browser / device is not capable of Geolocation
   lookup functionality. Places their location at centre of Auckland. */    
function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, addInfowindow, defaultPos) {
    if (browserHasGeolocation) {
        infoWindowContentString = "Sorry, we can't get your location."; 
    } else {
        infoWindowContentString = "Your current browser does not support Geolocation.";
    }
    addInfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: infoWindowContentString
        });
    map.setCenter(defaultPos);
    addMarker(defaultPos, addInfowindow);
    addDabblerArrayToMap(null);
}

/* Takes positions in dabblersArray and runs each through 
   the addMarkerWithTimeout function. Then calculates the 
   distance between user and dabblers.   */
function addDabblerArrayToMap(position1) {
    var distance;
    var dabblerLocation;
    deleteMarkers();
    position1 = centerPos;

    if (position1 == null) {
        for (var z = 0; z < dabblersArray.length; z++) {
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
            position: { lat: dabblersArray[z].lat, lng: dabblersArray[z].lng},
            map: map,
            icon: dabblers,
            draggable: false,
            clickable: true,
            id: dabblersArray[z].type
            }));
        }
    } else {
        var usersPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(centerPos.lat, centerPos.lng);

        for (var y = 0; y < dabblersArray.length; y++) {    
            dabblerLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(dabblersArray[y].lat, dabblersArray[y].lng);

            distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(usersPosition, dabblerLocation);
            distance = parseFloat(distance / 1000).toFixed(2);
            distanceArray.push(distance);

            dabblerInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: distance + "km"
            });

            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
            position: { lat: dabblersArray[y].lat, lng: dabblersArray[y].lng },
                map: map,
                icon: dabblers,
                draggable: false,
                clickable: true,
                id: dabblersArray[y].type
            }));
            dabblerInfoWindow.open(map, markers[y]);
        }
    // I shouldn't need to add this here, but have tried to set Center
       position manually again here to no avail also.
    map.setCenter(centerPos);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be easy to solve your problem if you create jsfiddle for this.

Comment: I don't really think the downvote is necessary, but hey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the order you are doing things.  The `map.setCenter` to the user's position runs before the time outs fire on the `addMarkerWithTimeout` calls.  When those markers are added to the map, their infowindows open, which centers the map to show the last infowindow opened.

one option to fix this is to set `disableAutoPan: true` on the infowindows.

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/La45rwh4/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var neighborhoods = [{
  lat: -36.862338,
  lng: 174.7425013
}, {
  lat: -36.867204,
  lng: 174.7692113
}, {
  lat: -36.848362,
  lng: 174.7426733
}, {
  lat: -36.845028,
  lng: 174.7748043
}, {
  lat: -36.862644,
  lng: 174.7340973
}, {
  lat: -36.862775,
  lng: 174.7836023
}];
var markers = [];
var map;
var dabblers = "https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png";
var yourLocation = "https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red.png";
var myLocationIconArray = [];
var hasHappened = false;
var infoWindowContentString = '';
var dabblerInfoWindow = null;
var addInfowindow;
var distanceArray = [];
var defaultPos = {
  lat: -36.8527785,
  lng: 174.7617562
};
var centerPos;

var dabblersArray = [{
  lat: -36.862338,
  lng: 174.7425013,
  type: 'sweet'
}, {
  lat: -36.867204,
  lng: 174.7692113,
  type: 'sweet'
}, {
  lat: -36.848362,
  lng: 174.7426733,
  type: 'sweet'
}, {
  lat: -36.845028,
  lng: 174.7748043,
  type: 'savoury'
}, {
  lat: -36.862644,
  lng: 174.7340973,
  type: 'savoury'
}, {
  lat: -36.862775,
  lng: 174.7836023,
  type: 'savoury'
}];

/* Initializes map with custom styles, centers location, 
   and defines Map UI */
function initMap() {
  var customMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType([{
    stylers: [{
      hue: '#8c8c8c'
    }, {
      visibility: 'simplified'
    }]
  }, {
    elementType: 'labels',
    stylers: [{
      visibility: 'off'
    }]
  }, {
    elementType: 'landscape',
    stylers: [{
      color: '#e6e6e6'
    }]
  }, {
    featureType: 'road',
    stylers: [{
      color: '#ffffff'
    }]
  }, {
    featureType: 'road.highway.controlled_access',
    stylers: [{
      color: '#cccccc'
    }]
  }, {
    featureType: 'road.arterial',
    stylers: [{
      color: '#cccccc'
    }]
  }, {
    featureType: 'water',
    stylers: [{
      color: '#dce6e6'
    }, {
      "lightness": -10
    }, {
      "saturation": -30
    }]
  }, {
    featureType: 'poi',
    stylers: [{
      visibility: 'off'
    }]
  }, {
    featureType: 'transit.line',
    stylers: [{
      visibility: 'off'
    }]
  }], {
    name: 'Custom Style'
  });
  var customMapTypeId = 'custom_style';
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -36.8527785,
      lng: 174.7617562
    }, // Auckland City coords
    zoom: 15,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    zoomControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    fullscreenControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, customMapTypeId]
    }
  });
  map.mapTypes.set(customMapTypeId, customMapType);
  map.setMapTypeId(customMapTypeId);
  map.setOptions({
    draggable: false,
    zoomControl: false,
    zoomControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER
    },
    scrollwheel: false,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true
  });
  drop();
}

/* Takes positions in neighborhoodsArray and runs each through 
   the addMarkerWithTimeout function */
function drop() {
  var delay = 800;
  for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) {
    addMarkerWithTimeout(neighborhoods[i], i * 200 + delay);
  }
}

/* Takes position (lat / long) and timeout parameters and converts 
   into Google Map Markers. Then adds to Google Map. */
function addMarkerWithTimeout(position, timeout) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      icon: dabblers,
      draggable: false,
      clickable: false
    }));
  }, timeout);
}

/*  Clears original markers from map and sets relative arrays to [] */
function deleteMarkers() {
  for (var x = 0; x < markers.length; x++) {
    markers[x].setMap(null);
  }
  markers = [];
  neighborhoods = [];
}

/* Adds your location & infoWindow to map after signIn */
function addMarker(location, addInfowindow) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    icon: yourLocation,
    draggable: false,
    clickable: true
  });
  if (addInfowindow == null) {
    var myLocationInfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: "Your location",
      disableAutoPan: false
    });
    myLocationInfowindow.open(map, marker);
    myLocationIconArray.push(marker);
  } else {
    var myLocationInfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: infoWindowContentString,
      disableAutoPan: true
    });
    myLocationInfowindow.open(map, marker);
    myLocationIconArray.push(marker);
  }
}

/* Checks if Users browser / device is capable of Geolocation. If it is, gets current position */
function getUserLocation(onComplete) {
  map.setOptions({
    draggable: true,
    zoomControl: true,
    scrollwheel: true,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: false
  });

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      centerPos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      map.setCenter(centerPos);
      addMarker(centerPos);
      onComplete();
    }, function() {
      handleLocationError(true, addInfowindow, map.getCenter());
    });
  } else {
    //Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleLocationError(false, addInfowindow, map.getCenter());
  }
}

/* Removes elements, and adds Dabblers to map */
function runAllChainEvents() {
  getUserLocation(addDabblerArrayToMap);
}

/* Handles error if Users browser / device is not capable of Geolocation
   lookup functionality. Places their location at centre of Auckland. */
function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, addInfowindow, defaultPos) {
  if (browserHasGeolocation) {
    infoWindowContentString = "Sorry, we can't get your location.";
  } else {
    infoWindowContentString = "Your current browser does not support Geolocation.";
  }
  addInfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: infoWindowContentString,
    disableAutoPan: true
  });
  map.setCenter(defaultPos);
  addMarker(defaultPos, addInfowindow);
  addDabblerArrayToMap(null);
}

/* Takes positions in dabblersArray and runs each through 
   the addMarkerWithTimeout function. Then calculates the 
   distance between user and dabblers.   */
function addDabblerArrayToMap(position1) {
  var distance;
  var dabblerLocation;
  deleteMarkers();
  position1 = centerPos;

  if (position1 == null) {
    for (var z = 0; z < dabblersArray.length; z++) {
      markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {
          lat: dabblersArray[z].lat,
          lng: dabblersArray[z].lng
        },
        map: map,
        icon: dabblers,
        draggable: false,
        clickable: true,
        id: dabblersArray[z].type
      }));
    }
  } else {
    var usersPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(centerPos.lat, centerPos.lng);

    for (var y = 0; y < dabblersArray.length; y++) {
      dabblerLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(dabblersArray[y].lat, dabblersArray[y].lng);

      distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(usersPosition, dabblerLocation);
      distance = parseFloat(distance / 1000).toFixed(2);
      distanceArray.push(distance);

      dabblerInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: distance + "km",
        disableAutoPan: true
      });

      markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {
          lat: dabblersArray[y].lat,
          lng: dabblersArray[y].lng
        },
        map: map,
        icon: dabblers,
        draggable: false,
        clickable: true,
        id: dabblersArray[y].type
      }));
      dabblerInfoWindow.open(map, markers[y]);
    }
    // I shouldn't need to add this here, but have tried to set Center
    //    position manually again here to no avail also.
    // setTimeout(function() {
    map.setCenter(centerPos)
      //}, 5000);
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#map {
  height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<button onClick="runAllChainEvents();">Sign in</button>
```