# How to stop Google Maps from centering on inserted Info Windows

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a map which I am populating with markers and info windows dynamically. The issue I'm having is that after populating the map, it re-centers automatically on the info windows (but not very well).

It also appears to be centering a few times, and I think it tries to center on the last x added ones (it's not the last, but it's definitely not them all either).

Why this is of particular importance to me is I am populating Info Windows for two cities, and doing so city-by-city, and the map always ends up off-center of the second city (and all its info windows).

I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chisnallio/2zrL7cx3/) to show the behavior. Adding pins does not re-center, but adding info windows does. (they populate SE of the starting position)

**javascript:**

```
var map;
var markers;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -30,
      lng: 150
    },
    zoom: 8
  });
  markers = [];
}

function fire1() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let position = {
      lat: -34.397 + Math.random() - 0.5,
      lng: 150.644 + Math.random() - 0.5
    }
    let point = new window.google.maps.InfoWindow({
      position: position,
      content: `<span>${i}</span>`
    })
    point.open(map)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent opening an InfoWindow from changing the map's center, set the `disableAutoPan` property to true.  From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/info-window#InfoWindowOptions.disableAutoPan):

> **disableAutoPan**
>   Type:  boolean optional
>   Disable auto-pan on open. By default, the info window will pan the map so that it is fully visible when it opens.

```
let point = new window.google.maps.InfoWindow({
  position: position,
  content: `<span>${i}</span>`,
  disableAutoPan: true
})
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/kcumj17n/)

Related questions:

- [Google Maps API - maps.setCenter doesn't seem to be centering to users position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39450281/google-maps-api-maps-setcenter-doesnt-seem-to-be-centering-to-users-position)
- [Center google map on kml, not location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43669010/center-google-map-on-kml-not-location)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var markers;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -30,
      lng: 150
    },
    zoom: 8
  });
  markers = [];
}

function fire1() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {
        lat: -34.397 + Math.random() - 0.5,
        lng: 150.644 + Math.random() - 0.5
      },
      map: map
    });
    markers.push(marker);
  }
}


function fire2() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let position = {
      lat: -34.397 + Math.random() - 0.5,
      lng: 150.644 + Math.random() - 0.5
    }
    let point = new window.google.maps.InfoWindow({
      position: position,
      content: `<span>${i}</span>`,
      disableAutoPan: true
    })
    point.open(map)
  }
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

.explanation {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  left: 200px;
  top: 20px;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 70px;
  border: 2px #666 inset;
}

.fire {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  left: 20px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

#fire1 {
  top: 60px;
}

#fire2 {
  top: 100px;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
<button onclick="fire1()" id="fire1" class="fire">
  Insert Markers
</button>
<button onclick="fire2()" id="fire2" class="fire">
  Insert InfoWindows
</button>
<div class="explanation">When I add markers the map center remains still; but when I add info windows, the map seems to try and center them (badly) - how to I keep the map still?
</div>
```